# How can I check VB, console application, user input to make sure they entered a valid number?

Tags: .net, vb.net, decimal, type-conversion

Vb is not my language of choice , but I have to do this for school and I'm not having a very easy time with VB's documentation.
I'm just creating a very simple console application that accepts user input: degrees in Celsius, and converts it into Fahrenheit. I want to make sure that if the user just hits enter without entering the degrees in Celsius, then an if else statement will catch and write to enter Celsius again. Here's what I've tried:

```
Module Module1
'Chapter 2:     Celcius to Fahrenheit
'Programmer:    Scott McPherson
'Date:          February 2, 2012
'Purpose:       To Convert User Input Celcius to Output Fahrenheit
'
'Declaration
    Dim decCelcius As Decimal = 0
    Dim decFahrenheit As Decimal = 0

Sub Main()
    'Input in Celcius
    Console.Write("Enter the degrees in Celsius: ")

    Console.WriteLine()
    If CDec(Console.ReadLine()) <> 0 Then
        decCelcius = CDec(Console.ReadLine())
        decFahrenheit = 1.8 * decCelcius + 32
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Don't make me ask again! ENTER THE DEGREES IN CELSIUS: ")
        decCelcius = CDec(Console.ReadLine())
        decFahrenheit = 1.8 * decCelcius + 32
    End If
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Degrees in Fahrenheit = " & decFahrenheit)
    Console.Read()
End Sub

End Module
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem with your current method of validating the input is that the `CDec` operator doesn't return an error when the conversion fails. You're compensating for this by checking to see if the entered value was converted to 0, but that means you're going to display the rude error message if they enter `0`, which is actually a valid temperature value!

So rather than the `CDec` operator, you probably want to switch to using the [`Decimal.TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx), which has the advantage of separating the success/failure from the actual converted value.

The [simple overload of this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) accepts only two parameters: the string value you want to convert (in your case, as returned by the `Console.ReadLine()` method) and a reference (in VB.NET terms, a value that is passed `ByRef`) to a variable of type `Decimal` that will be filled in with the result of the conversion, if it is successful. The function returns a `Boolean` value that indicates success or failure.

You could get away with using this simple overload, but it's probably "better" to use the [somewhat more complicated version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73.aspx) because it allows you to specify the culture to use when attempting to parse the specified value. Since some cultures use periods (`.`) as the decimal separator, and others use the comma (`,`), this is necessary for a culture-neutral application. That might be a bit too forward-looking in your case, though. :-)

Beyond fixing that immediate problem, it would also be better to replace your `If`/`Else If` statements with a `While` loop. That way, it will keep running over and over until the user manages to enter a valid number. This not only gives the user as many chances as they need, but it saves you from having to duplicate your code inside both of the `If` blocks.